# Gstreamer min-latency between frames not proper in appsrc

Tags: windows, qt, gstreamer

I set the `min-latency` property on my element `appsrc` to `5ms` . The `need-data` signal is mapped to a callback where I push frames. But the time difference between two frames on my sink pad is random(not 5 millisecond). At times two frames arrive at same millisecond. What property should I set to get the time interval between the frames even?

Comment: Please read the following : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

appsrc is for sending frames, so I assume you meant "At times two frames are *requested* from the callback in the same millisecond" (not *arrive*).

Because of scheduling, it is not possible to time the callbacks in milliseconds.  Probably it is also not neccessary for your application.  You should look into specifying your frame rate in the [caps property of your appsrc](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-appsrc.html#GstAppSrc--caps).

Comment: thank you for your reply.  But the frame rate property doesnt maintain frame delay between frames in milliseconds.